# Fast database solutions for Python Programming

Tags: python, database

Situation: Need to deal with large amounts of data (~260MB CSV datafile of about 50B of data per line)

Problem: If I just read from the file every time I need to deal with it, it will take a long time. So I decided to push everything into a database. I need a fast database infrastructure to handle the data as I need to do a lot of reading and writing.

Question: What are the faster choices for database in Python?

Additional information 1: The data comprises of 3 columns and I do not see myself needing anymore than that. Would this mean that a NoSQL database is preferred?

Additional information 2: However, if in the future I do need more than one database working together, would it be better to go for a SQL database?

Additional information 3: I think it would help to mention that I am looking at a few different DBs (MongoDB, SQLite, tinydb), but do suggest other DBs that you know are faster.

Comment: At only 260MB, why not just do it all in memory?

Comment: I am running a lot of things at the same time, and I only have 1GB memory as I am running it on an RPi compatible SBC.

Comment: SQLite is enough as you are dealing with little amounts of data.

Comment: Agree with SQLite, unless the data is more key/value oriented, then BDB.

Comment: key/value meaning dictionaries-like?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this same situation many times and I wanted something faster than a typical relational database. Redis is very fast and scalable key/value database. You can get started quickly using the [Popoto ORM](https://github.com/tomcounsell/popoto)

Here is an example:

```py
import popoto

class City(popoto.Model):
    id = popoto.UniqueKeyField()
    name = popoto.KeyField()
    description = popoto.Field()


for line in open("cities.csv"):
    csv_row = line.split('\t')
    City.create(
        id=csv_row[0],
        name=csv_row[1],
        description=csv_row[2]
    )

new_york = City.query.get(name="New York")
```

This is the absolute fastest way to store and retrieve data without having to learn the nuances of a new database system.

Keep in mind that if your database grows beyond 5GB, an in-memory database like Redis can start to become expensive compared to slower disk-based databases like Postgres or MySQL

full disclosure: I help maintain the open source Popoto project

Comment: 1. Is sqllite 3(with in memory option) is slower thean redis ? and 2. does redis supports cuncurrency like can we read(multiple read) and write at the same time ?

Comment: 1. yes, because most queries are simply a hash lookup 2. yes Redis supports blocking and non-blocking transactions to control concurrency. Also using the pipelining feature, you can execute a 1000s of reads and writes together in a single DB call.
Popoto however does not expose concurrency in the Python commands. Pipelines are used behind the scenes automatically and also available as an explicit option.